# Excercise Band Excerises

Tags: safety, obesity, resistance-cord

I need some advice on safety and resistance band exercises. I have a resistance band, and it is smaller than me because I saw one person doing an exercise in which the resistance band was on their shoulder and they were doing squats. How safe is those exercises, because I am trying to engage in more upper body resistance band exercises that safe for me because I am obese. I respect any feedback on the issue. In case of a summary of my two questions is basically safety of resistance band exercises, and those exercises particularly being upper body excercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exercise bands are perfectly safe and recommended by many! However, make sure you're using the correct type. I'd suggest something like [these](https://innerstrengthproducts.ca/collections/white-lion-bands/products/41-band-pack) which are durable with a good length. Make sure you're not using something like a hip circle band as that will be much too small.

I've personally only heard of one exercise band breaking at my local gym. It was while someone was doing "monster walks". The band would constantly rub on the ground and friction wore it down over time.

Comment: Would a question about types of exercises to do for the upper body be off-topic because I would like to ask one?

Comment: For sure. You might be able to find some that have already been asked too.